# Does unity load a 3d model which is stored in android device internal storage?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing an `android` app with `unity` in which I want to access the 3d model which is stored in a folder which is in my phone's internal storage and the path of the folder is:/storage/emulated/0/Experiment/test/test.obj.

Does `unity` load that test.obj model from that path? Does `unity` support that?

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can load data from android folders. (suitable permissions might be required)

no, unity doesnt support runtime loading .obj files (but there are several plugins to parse obj files available, paid and free)

for reading files, can use:

- regular System.IO
- unity UnityWebRequest for local file:///

Check device log for errors and print out your path to double check you are trying access correct location.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can load data from android folders in unity?Thanks for the reply.

Comment: that's a different/larger topic already.. better search unity forums, plenty of similar threads. (and if you post here or there, show your code also)

Comment: Actually,I am new to unity and I am trying with the following code:                                                 
        GameObject gameObject = Resources.Load<GameObject>("abc");
        Instantiate(gameObject);   and the model is rendered in my android device.Now I am trying to fetch the 3d model from android internal storage and render it in my android device.